# Tips for constructing small PCBs with only one SOIC

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-assembly

So I'm going to repackage [this](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en557594) breakout module for simple SPI with a bus-powered LED light strip. It seems expensive and unnecessary for advanced SMT assembly equipment and since its a small PCB with only a few SMDs. What techniques should I employ for this simple SMT assembly?

Comment: see http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/36

Answer (score 4):

Don't be afraid of SMT work, it's easy once you get the hang of it - just as easy as through hole with the right equipment.

A few tips - in the same spirit as the useful Sparkfun tutorial Vicatcu mentions, just from my personal view:

- Grab yourself a half decent *temperature controlled* soldering iron and hot air tool - these can be separate or in one "rework station". The YH899D is a very cheap rework station which performs very well for the price - I have one here and have used it plenty for a year or so with no problems (for TQFP, QFN, SOIC, 0603 R&C, etc) The tips are compatible with Hakko irons so easy to find.

[image: Rework Station]

- Get some decent [anti-static tweezers](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4pc-Professional-Safe-Anti-static-Tweezer-Maintenance-Repair-Curved-Tool-Kit-ESD-/330808577697?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item4d05ba4ea1#ht_2736wt_1186) for placing components.

[image: Tweezers]

- Design a PCB and get it made cheaply. [ITead](http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?cPath=19_20) or [SeedStudio](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/fusion-pcb-service-p-835.html?cPath=185) both have very cheap prototyping services (from only $9.90 for 10 boards! - hard to beat even if you make your own). ITead has a 4-layer option, which is the only cheap one I know about (used it a few times with no issues)
  The wait can be up to 3-4 weeks (generally quicker)
- Whilst waiting for the board you may want to practice soldering/desoldering on some old boards. There are loads of tutorials around for SMT soldering, some good answers on here too, so I won't go into detail apart from a few small points: flux is your friend, make sure you have plenty of it and use it liberally. Learn to drag solder for the fine pitch ICs - TQFP, SOIC, etc; get a hoof tip for this. Get some good quality wick to clean up bridges.
- Get more than one of each component so if you make a mess you can try again - you'll have 10 boards to get it right with if you use one of the services above.

Comment: In addition to all the above I really like to have a good pick for clearing shorts while drag soldering:  http://www.stanleysupplyservices.com/product-detail.aspx?pn=475-991  I can do it faster and without wick that way.  With a little practice you should be able to do something simple like that in no time.

Comment: For prototyping PCB services, [BatchPCB](https://www.batchpcb.com) can't be beat if you only need one board($2.50/sq inch+$10 for setup fee (setup fee only applied once per run of boards)) and [OSHPark](http://oshpark.com/) can't be beat if you want to have more than 1 board($5/sq inch for 3 boards no setup fee)